# How do I the get entire tab to act in unison?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to get the tab to act in unison with the icon within it when the pointer is hovering over it. I want what is blue to turn white and what is white to turn blue.

I want the icon to transform and be seen when I'm hovering over the tab.

Problem:
As of now, when the pointer enters the tab it completely turns blue, covering the icon. I have to hover over the icon itself for it to be shown.

[Full code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/elohi/wq2zuayx/1/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="board-inner">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <div class="liner"></div>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#pictures" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="round-tabs one"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></span></a>
            </li>
                      <br><br> <br> 
            <li>
                <a href="#info" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="round-tabs"><i class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></i></span> 
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change some of your hover selectors

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/7zL7xg98/1/)

Change this:

```
.board-inner li a span .fa-lg:hover { 
color: #fff;
}
```

To this:

```
.board-inner li a span:hover .fa-lg { 
color: #fff;
}
```